# Error parsing XML not well-formed (invalid token) in android Studio

Tags: android, xml

In android studio I have the following XML file which is giving me an error when parsing the XML

> not well-formed (invalid token)

I don't know the cause of it and I also get another error:

> "Can't resolve symbol R"

I did a clean build but it didn't help. Could anybody help?

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/wbackground"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Welcome To Health Calculator"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="30sp"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:text="Blood Calculator"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
       android:layout_width="270dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonshapewelcome"
       android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
       android:shadowRadius="5"/>  
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:text=" Calculator"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
       android:layout_width="270dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonshapewelcome"
       android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
       android:shadowDx="0"
       android:shadowDy="0"
       android:shadowRadius="5" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you closing </LinearLayout> ?

Comment: Sorry my bad mistakenly did'nt written it here in the code but it is present in code and still error

Answer (score 0):

1. Makes sure to have `Linearlayout` have closing tag. `<LinearLayout></LinearLayout>`
2. `android:background="@drawable/wbackground"` check all the drawables used in your xml, are present in your `res/drawables` (or appropriate drawable folders)

Comment: All the drawables are present in the folders and i have closing tag mistakenly didn't write here

Comment: Check if any other `res` files are having issue. If so what line it is having issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an invalid Manifest. Your activity layout looks fine (except you're missing the closing tag - but your comment says that you have it).

An error in the manifest XML will lead to "cannot resolve symbol R" and then all of you drawables (and strings, etc.) will be invalid.

Also, check that you have named your file correctly (no spaces, no leading number, no caps, etc.). That can cause an error also.